# Index names of dataframe not getting printed in the output of xlsx writer

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, xlsxwriter

My dataframe upi looks like:

```
               triggered_value  triggered_gnv   
triggered_value 2                 3
triggered_gnv   10                 5
```

this is a `transpose()` output

I am using the following to output this into excel

```
!pip install xlsxwriter
import io
import boto3
import xlsxwriter
bucket = 'adhoc-query-data'
filepath = xxx
with io.BytesIO() as output:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        upi.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='reminder_experiment',startrow=2,index=False)
        worksheet = writer.sheets['reminder_experiment']
        worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Updated on:')
        worksheet.write(0, 1, f"{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")
        
    data = output.getvalue()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=filepath, Body=data)
```

but in my excel sheet the output does not include my index / row titles which are on the left. It only prints the column names

How can i write the dataframe exactly to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the index is turned off here:

```py
upi.to_excel(..., index=False)
```

You can either set it to `True` or omit it, since it is the default.